# OleDbConnection string and unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, oledb

In my program I'm reading data from a HTML file, in this file however there are sometimes pieces of text-data containing unicode characters wich get converted back to UTF-8 :

Michèle  --> MichÃ¨le

I'm using the following code to retrieve the data from the file :

```
        string ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"HTML import;CharacterSet=UNICODE;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=0;TypeGuessRows=0\";", fileName);

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                string pageName = "bestelformulier";
                cm.CommandText = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", pageName);
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                var dt = ds.Tables[0];

                ProcessRows(dt);
            }
        }
```

I've searched google trying to find out how to 'tell' OleDb to use Unicode when reading the file but I haven't found a solution yet (using extended property CharacterSet=UNICODE doesn't seem to work). Can anyone here help me out ?

thanks,
Jurjen.

20-mrt-2012, 15.41

I have not found a solution but I created a small function te restore the string to it's original state, so that's what I'm using now for all string fields after reading the data.

```
    private static Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    public static string RepairUTF8(this string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = iso.GetBytes(value);

        if (bytes.Any(o => o.Equals(195)))
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        }

        return value;
    }
```