# Reading special characters from text file using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm having problems reading non ASCII chars from a text file using OleDbConnection. Any ideas?

Here is the **test method** I've used to replicate the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var arquivo = new FileInfo(@"P:\import.txt");

    string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"{0}\\\";Extended Properties=\"Text;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited\"", arquivo.DirectoryName);
    var conexaoFonteDados = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conexaoFonteDados.Open();

    string instrucaoSql = "SELECT * FROM [" + arquivo.Name + "]";

    var com = new OleDbCommand(instrucaoSql, conexaoFonteDados);
    if (com.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        com.Connection.Open();
    }

    var drDadosImportacao = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    while (drDadosImportacao != null && drDadosImportacao.Read())
    {
        object valorImportado = drDadosImportacao["Column"];
        Console.WriteLine(valorImportado);
    }
}
```

Here is the **import.txt** file content:

```
Column
a
b
ç
á
```

Here is the output from the **Console**:

```
a
b
?
?
```

### Work around solution

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773538/oledbconnection-string-and-unicode), you can convert the string to the correct encode using a method similar to this:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    private static readonly Encoding Iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    public static string RepairUtf8(this string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Iso.GetBytes(value);

        return bytes.Any(o => o.Equals(195)) ? Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) : value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to figure out what encoding your text file uses. Then specify the text encoding in your connection string.

As an example, this would be your connection string which also specifies UTF-8 encoding (`CharacterSet`). Replace `UTF8` with the actual encoding used by your text file:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"{0}\\\";Extended Properties=\"Text;CharacterSet=UTF8;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited\"",
    arquivo.DirectoryName
);
```

Since it is some (long) time ago since i used OleDB, i cannot say for sure if the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider understands the names of encodings such as UTF8, ISO-8859-1, etc... If it does not seem to work, try specifying the [codepage identifier of the encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756.aspx) instead of the encoding name (for example, instead of "*CharacterSet=UTF8*" you would specify "*CharacterSet=65001*").

Comment: Your encoding is probably ISO-8859-1 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm also from Brazil and I get that encoding mismatch a lot using UTF-8 ;)

Comment: Thank you for you help @elgonzo, but using the CharacterSet propertie the method threw the following exception: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid argument. If I used. I was able to find a workaround solution as I will describe it on my question.

Comment: I am sorry that my answer couldn't help you; but i am glad that you found a workaround nonetheless. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the codepage identifier! That did the trick for me: **`CharacterSet=65001` for UTF-8**